# Find and replace specific text with sed

Tags: unix, sed

I have a file with a lot of test cases what I have to do find "eapi(" and replace with "case( counter ,". here counter is start from 1 ,2 ..etc.

input file

```
eapi(price1(....))

eapi(price2(....))

eapi(price3(....))

eapi(price4(....))
```

Expected Results:

```
case(1,price1(....))

case(2,price2(....))

case(3,price3(....))

case(4,price4(....))
. . . .  .
```

I used below sed command but not working.

```
COUNTER=1
while read a
do
     sed 's/eapi(/case(`echo $COUNTER`,/' $a
     echo " $COUNTER "
     COUNTER=$[$COUNTER +1]
done < input
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

```
COUNTER=1
cat input.txt | while read a
do
    echo $a | sed "s/eapi(/case($COUNTER,/"
    echo " $COUNTER "
    COUNTER=$[$COUNTER +1]
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
i=1
while read -r line; do
        sed "s/eapi(/case($i,/" <<< $line
        ((i++))
done < $1
```

With your input the result is:

```
case(1,price1(....))
case(2,price2(....))
case(3,price3(....))
case(4,price4(....))
```

As far as I know you have to use double quotes in Sed for getting the content of a variable. So with the double quotes it is working.

Answer (score 0):

If the number is always the same you can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
while read a
do
  nr=$(echo $a | grep -oP 'eapi\(price\K([0-9]+)' )
  echo "$a" | sed 's/eapi(/case('$nr',/' 
done < input
```

Comment: This script will work with blank lines in input like you ask.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of replacement, you could use `awk`:

```
awk '/^eapi\(price/{sub(/eapi\(price/,"case(" ++c ",price")}1' file
```

This replaces the pattern `^eapi\(price` by adding the counter `c` and the wanted string.